# Github Actions skips Gradle task claiming it has no actions

Tags: java, github, gradle, copy, github-actions

I have a custom task in my build.gradle that just copies some stuff from JAVA_HOME, and it works perfectly locally, and I wanted to use it in a Github workflow. However the custom task doesn't get runned, saying "Skipping task as it has no actions". I'm not sure if that's supposed to mean that it could not find JAVA_HOME and thus the files, or if there's some other issue I have no idea about, but I can't figure out why this happens, or how to solve it.

**EDIT**: The workflow .yml file, because it was requested. Calling the task with --debug was what allowed me to find the line where it said Gradle was skipping the task. The branches part will be removed, it's only there for me to try to make it work without having to mess with tags too much.

```
name: Java CI with Gradle

on:
  push:
    branches: [master]
    tags:
      - 'v*.*.*'
  pull_request:
    tags:
      - 'v*.*.*'

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up JDK 11
      uses: actions/setup-java@v2
      with:
        java-version: '11'
        distribution: 'adopt'
    - name: Grant execute permission for gradlew
      run: chmod +x gradlew
    - name: Setup Gradle Wrapper
      run: gradle wrapper --gradle-version 6.8
    - name: Build with Gradle
      run: ./gradlew packageDistribution --debug
    - name: Release
      uses: softprops/action-gh-release@v1
      if: startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/tags/')
      with:
        files: "build/dist/FGO Tracker.zip"
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Also from the log (this was like like ~3500 of the task execution)

```
2021-05-10T16:44:35.073+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Task :copyStuff' started
2021-05-10T16:44:35.073+0000 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.internal.buildevents.TaskExecutionLogger] 
2021-05-10T16:44:35.073+0000 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.internal.buildevents.TaskExecutionLogger] > Task :copyStff
2021-05-10T16:44:35.073+0000 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter] Skipping task ':copyStuff' as it has no actions.
2021-05-10T16:44:35.074+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Completing Build operation 'Task :copyStuff'
2021-05-10T16:44:35.074+0000 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Task :copyStuff' completed
```

Task in build.gradle (before I forget to mention, I'm using Gradle 6.8, because 7.0 freaks out over duplicate modules in my non-modular JavaFX app):

```
task copyStuff {
    dependsOn("createExe")
    copy {
        from System.getenv("JAVA_HOME") + "/bin"
        into "$buildDir/launch4j/jre/bin"
    }
    copy {
        from System.getenv("JAVA_HOME") + "/lib"
        into "$buildDir/launch4j/jre/lib"
    }
    copy {
        from System.getenv("JAVA_HOME") + "/conf"
        into "$buildDir/launch4j/jre/conf"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the workflow yml file?

Comment: I mean, I can, but the issue is Gradle since it's Gradle that skips the task.

Comment: Yes but the yml file contains the commands that are executed. Also, please share the relevant parts of the build log.

Comment: What should `copyStuff` do? Did you define it in the `build.gradle`? Can you show that?

Comment: As I said in the post, it just copies some folders from JAVA_HOME, nothing super fancy, but I'll add it

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52951444/10871900) help? Especially the part
 using a `doLast`.

Comment: Yeah, I wrongly assumed what doLast would do and then never tried it out. Gave it a try and it worked, so at least this issue is fixed. Thanks.